# Moving questions TO webmasters

Tags: support, migration, stack-overflow

My primary interest is search engine optimization.   As such, Pro Webmasters is the stack site at which I can be most helpful.  However, I follow the SEO tag on StackOverflow as well.  Just that tag on StackOverflow has about the same volume of posts of all of Pro Webmasters.  About half the questions asked there are not implementation related and would have been better asked on Pro Webmasters.   Is there a shortcut I can use to recommend that those questions be moved to Pro Webmasters for StackOverflow?   I've been flagging them as "need moderator attention" with a comment that they should be moved.  However, very few of them are actually moved, many are closed, even while my flags are marked as "helpful".

Comment: That's a very good question. It's probably best asked at meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I raised this on stackoverflow meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169177/moving-questions-under-the-seo-tag-to-webmasters-stackexchange-com/169180

Comment: Good question and I been thinking the same for awhile, To be honest it seems that people just pass stuff here when its flagged, and a lot of the time they just don't FIT. There are many topics on a lot of stacks that should be migrated here.